# simple if condition not working in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, command

I have the below code where my `if` condition is not working in a simple shell script.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

run() {
cd /tmp/in/current; java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/tmp/in/logging/log4j2_Importer.xml -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -classpath /tmp/in/betl-runner/lib/*:/tmp/in/lib/* baag.betl.runner.Application --config /tmp/in/config/import.dev.properties.TODO --workflow import --inputDir "$1"
}

dev_path="/tmp/in"

mode=$1

if [ "$mode" = "$dev_path"  ]; then
   run "$mode" 
fi
```

In the `if` condition if I just do `if [ "$mode" = ""  ];` then somehow the code runs, but I don't know why the above `if` condition is failing.

Comment: IMHO, wouldn't `"$mode" = dev_path` should be `"$mode" = "$dev_path"` in your if condition?

Comment: yes i just changed but still not working

Comment: Why did u added java tag to it ?

Comment: because i am trying to run java code from this shell script if i just take the complete cd script, put it in shell script and then run it works...but a i am trying to make this code flexible then somehow its now working

Comment: How are you calling the script?

Comment: add `set -x` in your script to see what is really executed, mode might be empty.

Comment: if i add set -x and run the script then it returns like : + dev_path=/tmp/in
+ mode=   
                        + [  = /tmp/in ] ...looks like mode is empty but i dont know the reason as i am providing the path in dev_path variable

Comment: mode is empty, try `"${mode:-empty}"` if you see `empty` then it is a literal empty variable.

Comment: sorry i am quiet new to shell script ..can you please tell me where i need to do this ? and how do i assign actually the path in mode variable ?

Comment: Are you passing an argument when you call your script, eg. `$ myscript /tmp/in`?

Comment: no i am not passing any argument ..i am just running the script like ./file.sh

Comment: @Andrew, `mode=$1` means you need to pass an argument to your code, are you passing it while running it?

Comment: no i am not passing argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run your code by passing an argument to it(look at the statement `mode=$1` in your code), since OP confirmed in comments that NO arguments are being passed so code's if condition is failing.

Run it like (only an example here):

```
./script.sh "/tmp/in"
```

Where `script.sh` is your shell script code.

Since OP mentioned in comments in case OP don't want to pass arguments in that case, I would say:

> Argument passing means you are allowing people/code(whoever
>   running/calling code to pass their own values), so if you don't want
>   that then do something like mode="Your_new_value" in your code in
>   place of mode="$1". But IMHO please go through complete
>   need/requirement of your code/logic then only take some decision but
>   this is IMHO.

Comment: just want to know is there any other way around if i dont want to pass argument while running the script ?

Comment: @Andrew, Argument passing means you are making people free(whoever running/calling code to pass their own values), so if you don't want that then do something like `mode="Your_new_value"` in your code in place of `mode="$1"`. But IMHO please go through complete need/requirement of your code/logic then only take some decision but this is IMHO.

Comment: thanks i got it ...its working fine now...i have one more question actually where i want to make make this code little bit flexible ...i think i will create new question for this

Comment: @Andrew, Yes please one thread one question only, cheers and happy learning on this great site SO.

Comment: thanks :) i have created new question which is extend of this code. May be you can help quickly : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073491/how-to-assign-variable-in-shell-script

Answer (score 1):

In your script you set the value of `mode` to `$1` which is the first argument to your script. Try calling it like:

```
$ myscript /tmp/in
```

where `myscript` is the name of your shellscript file.

Comment: is there any other way around if i dont want to pass argument while running the script ?

Comment: If you don't want to pass in an argument, then you cannot use `mode` as its value is `$1`. In which case, skip the `if` altogether and just do `run $dev_path`