# how to assign variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have below shell script code which is working fine.

```
#!/bin/sh

run() {
  cd /tmp/in/current 
  java \
    -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/tmp/in/logging/log4j2_Importer.xml \
    -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom \
    -classpath /tmp/in/runner/lib/*:/tmp/in/lib/* \
    baag.runner.Application \
    --config /tmp/in/config/import.dev.properties.TODO \
    --workflow import \
    --inputDir "$1"
}

dev_path="/data/etl-dev/in/eurex"
simu_path="/data/etl-simu/in/eurex"

mode=$1

case "$mode" in
    "$dev_path" | "$simu_path" ) 
        run "$mode" 
        ;;
    *)  echo "error: invalid mode" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

But currently i can run this code only on dev database as you can see in run function script the `import.dev.properties.TODO` is set as dev. I want to make this flexible such that if the path is "/tmp/in/simu" for simu_path variable then the properties should be `import.simu.properties.TODO` and for dev_path it should be `import.dev.properties.TODO` so that it will run on the respective database.

I am not sure if its possible to set parametarized variable here. For example something like this `import.${varaible_here_dev_or_simu}.properties.TODO`

I want to keep the dev_path and simu_path as it is as it can be changed
 as i am passing this in argument

Comment: It would make your `run` function a lot easier to read if you put each statement on a separate line.

Comment: `import.$(basename "$1").properties.TODO`?

Comment: @TomFenech sure i did this..@kamil i will try with import.$(basename "$1").properties.TODO

Comment: If it's one long command, don't forget to escape the newlines with `\ ` (I edited to do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, bash unfortunately does not support constructs like associative arrays, which could be a possible solution, prior version 4.

If the paths for the environments all look like the same, you could write it like this.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

base_path="/tmp/in"

dev_env="dev"
simu_env="simu"

run() {
cd /tmp/in/current; java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/tmp/in/logging/log4j2_Importer.xml -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -classpath /tmp/in/runner/lib/*:/tmp/in/lib/* baag.runner.Application --config /tmp/in/config/import.$1.properties.TODO --workflow import --inputDir "$base_path/$1"
}

mode=$1

case "$mode" in
    "$dev_env" | "$simu_env" ) 
        run "$mode" 
        ;;
    *)  echo "error: invalid mode" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Note: In this implementation you would have to pass `dev` or `simu` to the script instead of the whole path. If you need to pass the complete path you have to change the `"$dev_env" | "$simu_env" )` to `"$base_path/$dev_env" | "$base_path/$simu_env" )`

**UPDATE**

Assuming the path structure and the environments are fixed, you can extract the environment with a simple regex and pass it to the function as the seconds parameter, like so:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

dev_path="/data/etl-dev/in/eurex"
simu_path="/data/etl-simu/in/eurex"
prod_path="/data/etl-prod/in/eurex"

environments="(dev|simu|prod)"

run() {
    cd /tmp/in/current; java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/tmp/in/logging/log4j2_Importer.xml -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -classpath /tmp/in/runner/lib/*:/tmp/in/lib/* baag.runner.Application --config /tmp/in/config/import.$2.properties.TODO --workflow import --inputDir "$1"
}

mode=$1

case "$mode" in
    "$dev_path" | "$simu_path" )
        environment=$(echo $mode | sed -E "s/.*${environments}.*/\\1/")
        run "$mode" $environment
        ;;
    *)  echo "error: invalid mode" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: the main problem is i dont want to change dev_path or simu path as this path i am pasiing in argument while running and it can be little bit different.. i have mentioned this in question

Comment: Okay understood. Another option would be to put create two arrays. One with the paths and a second with the corresponding environments. You would need a function to determine the index in the paths array and use it to get the correct value from the environments array. Seems a bit ugly but would work.

Comment: can we just simply put simu or dev wherever in mode and pass it the same during running the script..for example ./script.sh "dev" or ./script.sh "simu" then it will put the dev or simu variable value wherever necessary in script ? because right now my dev_path and simu_path are not fixed

Comment: As long as there is a specific naming scheme in your paths, you could extract the value. Otherwise you need to bring the path and environment together somehow.

Comment: yes there is specific naming scheme in the path ...for example /data/etl-dev/in/eurex  where i am reading the file and import.dev.properties.TODO where database properties are set in both place you can see dev keyword is present and same for simu...so now we need to make this flexible for identification

Comment: Great, then I would probably simply strip the prefix `/data/etl-` and suffix `/in/eurex` from the path, or, if the set of environments are fixed a simple regex to extract `(dev|simu)` from the path.

Comment: I updated my post. Simply spoken, you can extract the environment with a line like this: `environment=$(echo $mode | sed -E "s/.*(dev|simu).*/\\1/")`

Comment: this works fine as expected :) just small updated if i need to check for simu and prod then i will change the dev_path to prod_path="/data/etl-prod/in/eurex"
but in this case what change i neeed to do in environment=$(echo $mode | sed -E "s/.*(dev|simu).*/\\1/")  ?

Comment: You would just have to add the new environment within the brackets. Like so: `(dev|simu|prod)`. Or you define this part as an own variable, as shown above in my post. I updated the post, so it contains the code. Just make sure, the path is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Change `import.dev.properties.TODO` to `import."$2".properties.TODO` in run function. And use it like this.

```
run "$mode" "$whatever_you_name_it"
```

And we could ref this a bit

```
#!/bin/sh

path="${1:-/tmp/in}" # set /tmp/in as default path
mode="${2:-dev}"     # set dev as default mode
# or switch them if mode needs to be changed more recent
#path="${2:-/tmp/in}"
#mode="${1:-dev}"

run() {
    cd "$path"/current
    java -classpath "$path"/runner/lib/*:"$path"/lib/* baag.runner.Application \
         -Dlog4j.configurationFile="$path"/logging/log4j2_Importer.xml \
         --config "$path"/config/import.$1.properties.TODO" \
         -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom \
         --inputDir "$path/$1" \
         --workflow import
}

case "$mode" in
    "dev|simu") run "$mode" ;;
    *         ) echo "error: invalid mode" >&2; exit 1;;
esac
```

Comment: i dont understand "$whatever_you_name_it" what should i put here ...can you please explain ?

Comment: Whatever you want in place of `$2` in `import."$2".properties.TODO`

Comment: i think in this case should i use if condition instead of case beacause i am putting case condition togethere "$dev_path" | "$simu_path" so not understood

Comment: i think this syntax needs to changed in case condition dev|simu ? and also what argument should i pass while running the script ? previous i was running like  like ./script.sh "/tmp/in" and the main problem is i dont want to change dev_path or simu path as this path i am pasiing in argument while running and it can be little bit different

Comment: i have updated my answer ..as i said what if my dev_path and simu_path are like this then i think this will not work..

Comment: sorry its not working...one question can we just simply put simu or dev wherever in mode and pass it the same during running the script..for example ./script.sh "dev" or ./script.sh "simu"   then it will put the dev or simu variable value wherever necessary in script ?  because right now my dev_path and simu_path are not fixed